# Fabric Beta: Distributing with build tools

Tags: ios, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm using Xcode build server to prepare my builds. Running the Archive Post run script

```
${SOURCE_ROOT}/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
```

Source:-
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html

The test builds are not being emailed out and they do not appear on my Fabric dashboard.

Do I require to run the Fabric plug in on the build server? Or what other troubleshooting steps should I undertake?

Comment: Can you try setting `-notifications YES`? Also, can you let me know your bundle ID so I can check our backend?

Comment: set -notifications YES bundle ID is ClosedLoop.development

Comment: I'm seeing that bundle ID in two Fabric organizations and it looks like it's being distributed through Beta in one of them and an email was sent out. Can you share the last 5 digits of the API key you're using in the submit script so I can double check the organization?

Comment: That bundle id has been used across two Fabric organisations.

Comment: That bundle id has been used across two Fabric organisations. There have been manual archives done on one organisation. Its the one from the build server I'm trying to resolve now. A number of builds have been prepared today using the build server. The last 5 digits of the API key are 71040.

Comment: I'm not seeing any Beta distributions for ClosedLoop.development in the org with that API key. What are the last 5 digits of the Fabric secret and can you share the build server output after the /submit command is run?